DIscord Music bot not queing
I am trying to make a music bot for my own Discord server. Everything seems to be working and I get no error messages. But songs that are added to the que does not seem to start playing once the initial song is done. This is my current code:
def __init__(self, bot):
    self.bot = bot
    self.voice_clients = {}
    self.queues = {}
    yt_dl_options = {"format": "bestaudio/best"}
    self.ytdl = yt_dlp.YoutubeDL(yt_dl_options)

    self.ffmpeg_options = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn -filter:a "volume=0.25"'}

async def play_next(self, interaction: Interaction):
    if self.queues[interaction.guild.id] != []:
        # Fetch the first song in the queue
        link = self.queues[interaction.guild.id].pop(0)
        await self.play(interaction, link)
    else:
        await self.bot.disconnect()
        del client

@app_commands.command(name="play")
async def play(self, interaction: Interaction, *, link: str):
    try:
        if interaction.user.voice is None:
            return await interaction.response.send_message("Get in a voice channel first...", ephemeral=True)

        voice_client = await interaction.user.voice.channel.connect()
        self.voice_clients[interaction.guild.id] = voice_client
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

    if interaction.guild.id not in self.queues:
        self.queues[interaction.guild.id] = []

    if interaction.guild.id in self.voice_clients and self.voice_clients[interaction.guild.id].is_playing():
        self.queues[interaction.guild.id].append(link)
        await interaction.response.send_message("Added to queue!")
    else:
        await self.start_playing(interaction, link)

async def start_playing(self, interaction: Interaction, link: str):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    data = await loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: self.ytdl.extract_info(link, download=False))

    link = data['url']
    player = discord.FFmpegOpusAudio(link, **self.ffmpeg_options)

    self.voice_clients[interaction.guild.id].play(player, after=lambda e: asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(self.play_next(interaction), self.bot.loop))
    await interaction.response.send_message(f"Playing {data['title']}")

No errors in the terminal, respones are correctly sent to the user
